# How can I produce a plot showing the directional angles of my points?

Tags: r, data-visualization, circular-statistics

I want to be able to compare the angles of neighbours in a herd of hippos. I have data for the x and y coordinates and the angles that they are facing (using [imageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), angles are between -180 and 180 with 0 being a horizontal straight line across the middle of the image). I have plotted the $g(r)$ function to see whether my hippos 'like' to orient themselves towards individuals that are nearby, but I would love to be able **to compute a visual representation of their orientation in the herd** using `R`.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm not really `R` literate yet!

Comment: Take a look at the circular package. It has several plots that may help you, and also some nice functions.

Comment: I would be interested in learning more about what "$g(r)$" represents and how it is calculated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coding in R and not statistics.

Comment: Please edit your question to more clearly emphasize the statistical/data-vizualization aspects of your question over the 'what lines of R code should I type' aspects. Could you also clarify what $g$ is please?

Comment: The question is not so unclear "How *can* I produce a plot showing the directional angles of my points?" but it is off-topic since it is about 'production'. If we just change the title into "How *should* I plot the directional angles of my points?" then this question may be released from the closing tag and be open for people to give their thoughts on plotting data points while including directional information.

Answer (score 15):

It sounds like the data consist of vectors of (x,y) coordinates and the angles.  Let's simulate some as an example:

```
set.seed(43)
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(50)
angles <- runif(50, min=-pi, max=pi)
```

Plot the locations:

```
plot(x, y, pch=19, cex=0.8, col="Blue")
```

**Add arrows** to show the orientations at these points:

```
length <- 0.2
arrows(x, y, x1=x+length*cos(angles), y1=y+length*sin(angles), 
       length=0.05, col="Gray")
```

[image: Hippos]

Comment: This has really helped thank you so much! I'm working on adapting it for my data and am looking forward to seeing the plot output :) Thanks again!

Comment: The code should be corrected as R always works with angles in radians:  `cos(angles*pi/180) ` and  `sin(angles*pi/180) ` with  `angles ` between 0 and 360.

Comment: @DJack Thank you for pointing that out.  Fortunately in this case it makes little difference (and therefore I don't need to recompute the example), because a uniform distribution on $[-180,180]$ radians isn't much different than a uniform distribution on $[-\pi,\pi]$ radians (modulo $2\pi$), but it's important to get such details computationally correct.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer by @whuber.  The `ms.arrows` and `my.symbols` functions in the `TeachingDemos` package for R might be of interest.  They would also plot the arrows but you can give the anges directly rather than computing sine and cosine, it also makes it easier if you want the arrows centered on the points rather than originating from the points.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, I'll send this to my supervisor and we shall have a go at all your suggestions!